# ASP.NET MVC - Current Folder Of View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how to get the current *folder* of the view being called?  I'm using AreasLib as well, so I need to get it dynamically without prefixing paths.  So for example, if I do `http://localhost/myarea/mycontroller/myaction` it will give me the path of `Project/Areas/myarea/Views/mysubsystem`.  So yeah, it needs to be the folder that the *view* is in.

**EDIT**: It's either that, or editing [MvcSiteMap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) source code to deal with [AreasLib](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx).  I'm not really equipped with the skills, or the time more importantly to deal with it.

**FINAL**

It's not pretty, but I had no choice whatsoever. I'm using partial views to render the menu components using the following helper to find the correct one.  I'm not dealing with missing menu.ascx files in this version, but it's assumed there will always be one for now.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Intranet.Helpers
{
  public static class StaticMenuHelper
  {
    public static string StaticMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, string area, string controller)
    {
      if (area.Equals("root"))
      {
        return "/Views/" + controller + "/menu.ascx";
      }
      else
      {
        return "/Areas/" + area + "/Views/" + controller + "/menu.ascx";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following in my `Site.Master`.

```
<div id="menu">
    <% Html.RenderPartial(Html.StaticMenu(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())); %>
</div>
```

Until [MvcSiteMap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) has matured into something which can deal with [AreasLib](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx) then I'll have to use this.  I really, *really* don't have the time to be modifying that lib.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You don't want to know ;) Basically, because I'm using Phil Haack's AreasLib it means I can't use MvcSiteMap which means I can't dynamically generate my site navigation at all.  I'm in limbo.  So I'm getting the path so instead I will link to menu.aspx files that give me back the menu options I need.  Nasty, but they _are_ a view essentially, so it's not so bad.

Comment: Areas in ASP.NET MVC: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seem to me that, if you are calling into the view from a particular controller, it would be pretty straightforward to build the path from what you already know. If you need it in the view, you can just pass it in using a ViewData entry.

So, if you do

```
http://localhost/myarea/mycontroller/myaction
```

then the controller you are calling into already knows myarea, mycontroller, and myaction.  I assume you are building either a partial view or an Html helper method to handle the menu, so when you render your view pass myarea, mycontroller, and myaction into the view as ViewData variables.  In your view, pass those variables into your partial view or Html helper method.

Or, you can build your path from myarea, mycontroller, and myaction, and push the whole path into your view instead.

Usage:

```
<%= Html.Menu(ViewData["Area"], ViewData["Controller"], ViewData["Action"]) %>
```

Example function to calculate path:

```
string GetPath(string area, string controller, string action)
{
    return "/project/areas/" + area + "/" + controller + "/" + action 
}
```

**EDIT:** As Craig Stuntz pointed out, you can get the route values in a view (via ViewContext) without having to put them into ViewData first.  That means you can build your path directly in your Menu extension method, provided you can get **area** the same way.  I'm not sure whether Phil's stuff supports that or not.

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() 
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

Comment: Preferably a HtmlHelper so I can just do Html.Menu() and be done with it.  The problem I get is getting the URL without the parameters, and with AreasLib the controllers are nested into an Areas folder, so the URL http://localhost/accounts/contracts/mypage/param actually is in the folder project/areas/accounts/contracts

Comment: You can get the route values in a view (via ViewContext) without having to put them into ViewData first.

Answer (score 1):

Is that not the same as the view's namespace? That's easy enough to examine from the view itself.

Comment: You could be correct sir, although I'm not on my dev box until tomorrow.

Comment: It occurs to me this might vary depending on whether you have CodeBehind. I've never looked.